# unautomated subscription plugin

Tags: plugin-recommendation, subscription

I need to send some data to my subscribed visitors periodically.
Is there any plugin that just let users subscribe (enter their email) in my site that don't send anything automatically and I be able to use it manually?
I need a plugin that collect user emails (Using a subscription form) and let me send mass mails to them manually and nothing more!.

thanks

Comment: I'm not sure what you're needing. Do you want an automated plugin that doesn't send automated emails?

Comment: @BrianFegter: I need a plugin that collect user emails and let me send mass mails to them manually

Comment: Have you looked at Gravity Forms? They have a lot of add-ons for subscriptions etc...

Answer (score 1):

in case you don't afraid of some php, making a simple form that receives email address and insert it into wordpress database, is quite simple. this method allows you afterwards to generate mailing lists versatile as you like (divided to group of 50s, comma/tab seperated, etc.)

to do so the only plugin you'll need will be [php-code-widget](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/php-code-widget/) .